# Solidworks. Sphere from a Circle

Tags: solidworks

I am a new user of SolidWorks.

I know that we can make a sphere by using revolve boss with a semicircle. But when I make a circle and draw a diameter and try to revolve the circle around that diameter I get the following error:

"Sketch is open, self-intersecting, or intersects the centerline".

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch is open:*
Basic 3D-CAD; Sketches "must" describe a fairly simple closed loop. e.g. a triangle in its most basic form. Now note the **close loop** - a circle with a (e.g. diameter-forming) line across it will not work - if that is what you try.
To prepare for creating a sphere, you have to create half a circle with the ends of the diameter line marked as "connected" (attached, joined, coincident) to the ends of the half-circle. So; just "placed on top" is not enough.

*Self intersecting:*
The result (sphere) builds into itself.

*Intersects the centerline:*
Basically the same as above. The center of the revolve might not be perfectly centered, or an erratic choice as you initiate the revolve makes this happen.

*Tip of the day:*
*[www.freecaad.org](http://www.freecaad.org) has a totally free parametric and 3D-capable CAD, runs on Windows, Linux and (some?) Mac.*
*The currently stable version is v0.19, the community is active and often fairly quick in responses on questions.*
*There are numerous addons, and youtube is full of tutorial videos; quite a few for older versions though (which might describe deprecated methods).*